# I cannot find the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\gl on my laptop. How do I add it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Also does that mean opengl is not installed by default because I did check all the boxes when I installed visual studio community 2015. I couldn't find any clear answer anywhere. I'm supposed to add glut and glew header files to the aforementioned folder where gl.h and glu.h should already be there. But I couldnt find the folder include\gl itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Also does that mean opengl is not installed by default because I did check all the boxes when I installed visual studio community 2015. I couldn't find any clear answer anywhere.

You have to distinguish between:

- a fully featured OpenGL driver being installed (which unfortunately doesn't happen by default on Windows)
- the OpenGL development support files being available for your compiler environment.

As far as the compiler environment is concerned, since OpenGL-1.1 has been part of the Windows ABI contract since Windows-NT-4 all compilers that target the Windows-32 API *must* ship with the required support files.

To check if your compiler installation is complete try to compile and execute the following little program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( &glGetError ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL glGetError symbol available\n");
    }
}
```

It does not actually call an OpenGL function, but compiling it requires to link against opengl32.lib and testing for the symbol glGetError being non-NULL makes sure the linker will pull in a reference.

> I'm supposed to add glut and glew header files to the aforementioned folder

Don't! *Never* put anything manually into installation directories of the compiler toolchain. *Always* configure an auxiliary directory structure for header and library files, that you add to your projects' compiler include and linker search paths.

Install GLEW there. If you got the instructions to install GLEW into the compiler toolchain directory, disregard any other advice coming from the same source, as whoever is the source is apparently clueless about proper DevOps.

#### Update due to question in comment

In software development using 3rd party libraries is commonplace. You normally want to collect those libraries at a common location. Such libraries usually consist of header files, binaries and on some operating systems additional linker stubs. The binaries are built for a specific operating system and the linker stubs are made for specific compilers.

The following would be such a directory structure, inspired by the way *nix OSs organize their stuff

- `/local/include/`  gets all the headers
- `/local/i686-windows/bin` 32 bit Windows extra tooling executables
- `/local/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin` 32 bit Linux extra tooling executables
- `/local/i686-windows/lib` 32 bit Windows DLLs
- `/local/i686-windows/libmsvc` 32 bit Visual C++ linker stubs and static libraries
- `/local/i686-windows/libmingw` 32 bit GNU MinGW linker stubs and static libs
- `/local/i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib` 32 bit Linux SOs and static libraries
- `/local/x86_64-windows/bin` 64 bit Windows extra tooling executables
- `/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin` 64 bit Linux extra tooling executables
- `/local/x86_64-windows/lib` 64 bit Windows DLLs
- `/local/x86_64-windows/libmsvc` 32 bit Visual C++ linker stubs and static libraries
- `/local/x86_64-windows/libmingw` 32 bit GNU MinGW linker stubs and static libs
- `/local/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib` 64 bit Linux SOs and static libraries

Ok, so the above list may be a little bit excessive for a simple development environment. But say you're targeting 64 bit Windows, using the Visual C++ compiler, then you'd create a directory structure

- `/local/include/`
- `/local/x86_64-windows/bin`
- `/local/x86_64-windows/lib`
- `/local/x86_64-windows/libmsvc`

You'd add `GL/glut.h` and `GL/glew.h` (and the other header files) beneath `/local/include`, e.g.

```
/local/include/GL/glxew.h
/local/include/GL/glew.h
/local/include/GL/glut.h
/local/include/GL/wglew.h
```

The `.lib` files you put into `/local/x86_64-windows/libmsvc` and the DLLs into `/local/x86_64-windows/lib`. Then in your project build settings you can simply add `/local/x86_64-windows/libmsvc` as a linker search path. For the DLLs you should add `/local/x86_64-windows/lib` to your systems environment `PATH` variable, so that they are found when executing the programs you built. For deployment of those programs copy the required DLLs beside the EXE file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm still confused about the part "Always configure an auxiliary directory structure for header and library files". Would you mind explaining it in detail. Thank you :D